# How can I change background color of previously selected option?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to style previously selected option background-color (this light-blue one). I'm using Bootstrap 4, however I don't know how can I target currently selected option in CSS.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<select class="form-control" id="time-select">
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">Dowolna godzina</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">8:00-9:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">9:00-10:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">10:00-11:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">11:00-12:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">12:00-13:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">13:00-14:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">14:00-15:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">15:00-16:00</option>
  <option value="" class="fb-select-option">16:00-17:00</option>
</select>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Previously selected or currently selected? You seem to contradict yourself.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to know @isherwood

Comment: That was a question directed at you. To which are you referring... _previously_ selected or _currently_ selected? Your title says one thing and your post body another.

Answer (score -2):

You can give another class name that selected item and change it's background color with css

Comment: This answer needs more detail to be useful to the community.